# Smoothing signal from microphone - Hearthbeat

Tags: java, android, signal-processing, microphone

I'm working on project using oximeter.I want to smooth it out so I can use it for calculating hearthbeat. I'm gathering raw data from microphone , I put them in new array, lets say, `sData[]`.

Signal is really crazy and jumps all over the plot as expected, so i tried smoothing it using moving average. So my main code looks something like this.

```
writeAudioDataToFile(); 
for (int a = 0; a < sData.length; a++) {  
      tempAvg += Math.abs(sData[a]);
      if (a % numberOfSamplesAveraged == 0) { //Average from x samples
            if (myIndex > SAMPLE_SIZE - 1) {
                myIndex = 0;
            }
            tempAvg = tempAvg / numberOfSamplesAveraged;
            if (tempAvg > 500) {
                newDataArray[myIndex] = 500;
            }else{
                newDataArray[myIndex] = tempAvg;
     } //This is suppose to clear the high peaks.

     Log.d("isRecording - Average from " + numberOfSamplesAveraged + " numbers.", "newDataArray[" + myIndex + "] = " + newDataArray[myIndex]);
     tempAvg = 0;
     myIndex++;
   }
}
notifier.notifyObservers();
Log.d("Notifier", "Notifier Fired!");

Thread.sleep(20); //Still experimenting with this value
```

It looks so messy, but the plot (I'm using AndroidPlot btw) looks good but it is so inaccurate so I can't calculate the hearthrate from it. It has so much "Bounce" in "high" state. I found on internet that some kind of filter (Maybe IIR filter) will do the job. So i just wanna ask you guys how can i achieve a nice smooth chart? Is IIR filter the way to go? Is there any free applet/lib to smoothen it out?
This is my first question here so I'm really sorry if it is badly written.
If you will need any more information to help me, just ask.
Here is a picture how my chart looks like now.

http://oi62.tinypic.com/2uf7yoy.jpg // Cant post images im new here.

This is a lucky one though.
I need smoother output.

Comment: Could you please add a plot screenshot? I don't know how to answer the question, but I love plots.

Comment: There you go, i added a plot screenshot. But my plot is weak :(

Comment: please pay more attention to your tags next time. Instead of "signal-processing" you picked "signal" (which is for software interrupts) and "processing" (which is a programming language"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Noises, which occur at measurement, have high frequency. You should filter your signal, that is you should retain low frequency part of signal and suppress high frquency part of signal. You can do it, making a low-pass filter. It could be, for example, first-order inertial model. I suggest make a pass-band till ~~10 kHz, since people hear sound from 2 kHz to 20 kHz. Then appriopriate sample time is 0,0001 sec (0,1 ms). Discrete model has following equation:

`y[k] = 0.9048*y[k-1] + 0.09516*u[k-1]`,

where u is a measured vector (directly from microphone, input in our filter),
and y is a vector you want to analyze (so output from our filter).

As you can see,, you can calculate a sample number 1, and you can just assign 0 to the sample number 0. After all, you can try to plot y vector.

Comment: Hello Rafal , thank you so much for the equation. I've tried to implement it to my code, though my app ran only once, the plot line was super clear. That's awesome! But it keeps crashing and netcat gives nothing so i dont know why, here is my new commented code.

Comment: I'm glad you're happy. Where is your commented code? I don't see it.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/egJUtw61 . I hope it dont mind when i paste it on pastebin. I had some troubles pasting it directly here. This how it is was working without the equation, i dont know where it can have some troubles.

Comment: But tell me, what is a problem? Exactly?

Comment: Now its working like a charm, i made some little adjustments. Thank you so much Rafal ! I thought it will be hard but it is so easy ! Cheers man.